# What are the open sets in the interval $I = [0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Silly question but sometimes when I read textbooks that say things like "consider the space $S^1 \times I$" - without any extra information, I'm not really sure what the open sets in the $I$ are. Are we considering it as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3):

The open sets in the unit interval are the intersections of open sets in the reals with the unit interval.

In particular, $I$  is open in itself, as is $[0,1/2)$, even though these are not open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Edit** in response to the revised question asking about missing "extra information":

Without an *explicit* statement that spaces like these are to be thought of as subsets of real $n$-space you should view them as standalone topological spaces.

Comment: So in the example above, we are implicitly considering $S^1 \times I$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @JoshNg Only if you implicitly consider $S^1$ as subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ (and not, say, as quotient space $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$) and $I$ as subspace of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But usually there's no extra information in the textbooks or exercises.